# не открывается файл со скриптом

Tags: php

форма не переходит на файл "labels/load.php"
хотя написанный точно такой же, но чистый код работает идеально.
ниже приведены работающий и не работающий код соответственно.
Этот переходит на файл,

```
    <div class="loadrow">
        <form action="labels/load.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="Name">Name</label><br>
                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="Text">Text</label><br>
                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Text">
            </div>
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="Cost">Cost</label><br>
                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Cost">
            </div>
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="images">Images</label><br>
                <input class="bb2" type="file" name="images" accept="image/*">
            </div>
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="FST">Описание</label><br>
                <textarea class="TA" name="FST" cols="48" rows="8" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="load1">
                <label class="bb" for="Date">Date</label><br>
                <input class="bb2" type="date" name="Date">
            </div>
            
            <div class="klip">
                <button class="bb1" type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    
    
    </div>
```

а этот нет.

```
<?php require 'db.php' ;
session_start();
// база данных 



$title_site = 'Статус' ;

$log = $_POST['inputName'];
$pas = $_POST['inputPass'];
// получаем данные из формы



require 'labels/Head.php'  ;
// серверная часть 
?>
<body>

<div class="divMain1">

        <?php require 'labels/background.php' ?>
        <!-- шапка -->

    <div class="divMain2">

        <?php require 'labels/button.php' ?>
        <!-- кнопки -->

        <div class="divMain3">
        
            <div class="right_panel">
                <div class="log">
                    <form method="POST">
                    
                        <div>
                            <label class="kk" for="inputName">User Name</label><br>
                            <input class="kk2" type="text" name="inputName">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="kk" for="inputPass">Password</label><br>
                            <input class="kk2" type="password" name="inputPass" >
                        </div>
                        <button class="kk1" type="submit" name="ty">Submit</button>
                    
                    </from>
                </div>

            </div>
                    
                <?php
                if (isset($_COOCKIE['adm'])) {
                    ty();
                }; 

                if(isset($_POST['ty']))
                {
                    // Вытаскиваем из БД запись, у которой логин равняеться введенному
                    if ($query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['inputName'])."'")){
                        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

                        if($data['user_password'] === ($_POST['inputPass']))
                        {
                            $_SESSION['adm'] = 1 ;
                            ty();
                            $k=1;
                        } else {?>
                            <p class="pirojok">Неверный логин/пароль</p>

                       <?php
                        }
                    } else {?>

                            <p class="pirojok">Неверный логин/пароль</p>

                       <?php }
                } ?>
            <?php 
                if (($_SESSION['adm'] == 1) && ($k==0)) {
                    ty();
                };

                function ty(){ 
                    
            ?>

                    <div class="loadrow">
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="labels/load.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="Name">Name</label><br>
                                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="Text">Text</label><br>
                                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="Cost">Cost</label><br>
                                <input class="bb2" type="text" name="Cost">
                            </div>
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="images">Images</label><br>
                                <input class="bb2" type="file" name="images" accept="image/*">
                            </div>
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="FST">Images link</label><br>
                                <textarea class="TA" name="FST" cols="48" rows="8" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="load1">
                                <label class="bb" for="Date">Date</label><br>
                                <input class="bb2" type="date" name="Date">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="klip">
                                <button class="bb1" type="submit" name="load">Отправить</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    </div>  
                
                <?php

                    }
                ?>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<?php 


 ?>
```

у меня 2 варианта: или формы конфликтуют, или функция не работает корректно.
(Не кидайте страйки плиз, я еще учусь)

Comment: прекратите постоянно открывать и закрывать php тег. Один раз открыли и ВСЁ. Хватит. Вывод текста можно сделать через `echo`

Comment: я задолбусь экранировать каждые кавычки @peter

Comment: Что значит «не переходит»? Не делается переход на указанный action? Возникает ошибка в консоли? Раз переход делается в чистом HTML то сверьте результат вывода и убедитесь что он идентичен.

Comment: Во втором примере тег первой формы не закрыт. Форму в форме поддерживать нельзя. Измените </from> на правильный

Comment: Что вам мешает использовать одинарную кавычку при выводе через echo? Что вам мешает использовать мультистроку чтобы не писать кавычек вообще при выводе через echo?